# How to make a swipeable view with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried to make a SWIFTUI View that allows card Swipe like action by using gesture() method. But I can't figure out a way to make view swipe one by one. Currently when i swipe all the views are gone

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @ObservedObject var randomView: EventViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ForEach(randomView.randomViews,id:\.id){ view in
            view
                .background(Color.randomColor)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding()
                .offset(x: self.offset.width, y: self.offset.height)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { self.offset = $0.translation }
                        .onEnded {
                            if $0.translation.width < -100 {

                                self.offset = .init(width: -1000, height: 0)
                            } else if $0.translation.width > 100 {
                                self.offset = .init(width: 1000, height: 0)

                            } else {
                                self.offset = .zero
                            }
                    }
                )
                .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EventView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EventView(randomView: EventViewModel())
    }
}

struct PersonView: View {
    var id:Int = Int.random(in: 1...1000)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image("testBtn")
                .clipShape(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Circle()/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)

            Text("Majid Jabrayilov")
                .font(.title)
                .accentColor(.white)

            Text("iOS Developer")
                .font(.body)
                .accentColor(.white)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

With this piece of code, when i swipe the whole thing is gone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically your code tells every view to follow offset, while actually you want only the top one move. So firstly I'd add a variable that'd hold current index of the card and a method to calculate it's offset:

```swift
@State private var currentCard = 0

func offset(for i: Int) -> CGSize {
   return i == currentCard ? offset : .zero
}
```

Secondly, I found out that if we just leave it like that, on the next touch view would get offset of the last one (-1000, 0) and only then jump to the correct location, so it looks just like previous card decided to return instead of the new one. In order to fix this I added a flag marking that card has just gone, so when we touch it again it gets right location initially. Normally, we'd do that in gesture's `.began` state, but we don't have an analog for that in swiftUI, so the only place to do it is in `.onChanged`:

```swift
@State private var didJustSwipe = false

DragGesture()
    .onChanged {
        if self.didJustSwipe {
            self.didJustSwipe = false
            self.currentCard += 1
            self.offset = .zero
        } else {
            self.offset = $0.translation
        }
    }
```

In `.onEnded` in the case of success we assign `didJustSwipe = true`

So now it works perfectly. Also I suggest you diving your code into smaller parts. It will not only improve readability, but also save some compile time. You didn't provide an implementation of `EventViewModel` and those `randomViews` so I used rectangles instead. Here's your code:

```swift
struct EventView: View {

    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var currentCard = 0
    @State private var didJustSwipe = false

    var randomView: some View {
        return Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 400)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .padding()
            .opacity(0.3)
    }

    func offset(for i: Int) -> CGSize {
        return i == currentCard ? offset : .zero
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ForEach(currentCard..<5, id: \.self) { i in
                self.randomView
                    .offset(self.offset(for: i))
                    .gesture(self.gesture)
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
        }
    }

    var gesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged {
                if self.didJustSwipe {
                    self.didJustSwipe = false
                    self.currentCard += 1
                    self.offset = .zero
                } else {
                    self.offset = $0.translation
                }
        }
            .onEnded {
                let w = $0.translation.width
                if abs(w) > 100 {
                    self.didJustSwipe = true
                    let x = w > 0 ? 1000 : -1000
                    self.offset = .init(width: x, height: 0)
                } else {
                    self.offset = .zero
                }
        }
    }
}
```